# HTML5 Videojs Scrubbing NOT working while using FilePathResult

Tags: c#, javascript, html, google-chrome, video

I have written a test application in c# to play a video/mp4 file in videojs player and the source of the videojs player is a HttpRouteURL which calls into a controller method. This controller method returns a FilePathResult (a file) which is a video/mp4 file. The output video is working fine in IE 10 but it is not working perfectly in Chrome. In Chrome, when I scroll the "Seek Bar" to advance to a different part of the video, it again falls back to the current time and I am unable to scrub. It starts playing from the point it was playing from before I advanced the bar. I am guessing this issue is because I am not sourcing from a .mp4 file, but from a controller URL which returns a video file object. Can you please help me with this to enable video scrubbing in Chrome and Mozilla? Here's the controller code:

```
     public FilePathResult SendToView(string coursename, int year, string sem, int id)
    {

        List<Video> videoList = new List<Video>();

        Video video1 = new Video(
            "ece-550", 2012, "simpsons.mp4", "spring", @"C:\Products\PCRS", 550);


        Video video2 = new Video(
            "ece-573", 2013, "oceans.mp4", "fall", @"C:\samples", 573);


        Video video3 = new Video(
            "ece-773", 2013, "whistle.mp4", "spring",     @"C:\Products\PCRS\RnD\ffmpeg\input", 773);


        Video video4 = new Video(
            "his-501", 2012, "ducks.mp4", "fall", @"C:\", 501);

        videoList.Add(video1);
        videoList.Add(video2);
        videoList.Add(video3);
        videoList.Add(video4);


        foreach (var v in videoList)
        {
            if (coursename == v.Coursename && year == v.Year && sem == v.Sem && id ==  v.Id)
            {
                returnpath = v.VideoPath;
                finalpath = Path.Combine(returnpath, v.Filename);
            }
        }

        Response.Clear();
           Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=@finalpath");
            return File(finalpath, "video/mp4");      
    }
}
```

}

Here's the view snippet:

```
   <div>
   <!-- Using video.js -->
    <video id="videoPlayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
     controls preload="auto" width="640" height="480"
    data-setup='{}'>      
    <source src="@Url.HttpRouteUrl("Course", new { controller = "Course", action =     "SendToView", coursename = course , year = year, 
            sem = semester , id = ID})" type="video/mp4" />


   </video>


</div>
```

Thanks a lot, please help.

Comment: "I am guessing this issue is because I am not sourcing from a .mp4 file, but from a controller URL which returns a video file object."

why not create a static html file to test this assumption?